# 'Function Not Exported' Error When Using The RabbitMQ Delayed Message Exchange Plugin

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq

I am trying to get the [rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange) plugin working on centos 7 but I am encountering the error 'function not exported' when I try to publish a delayed message. The error seems to be an erlang issue when it attempts to run `erlang:system_time(milli_seconds)`. I don't know erlang at all but from what I can work out it looks as if the erlang module is either not imported or not installed. Any help would be great! :D

#### Versions

- rabbitmq: 3.6.5
- rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange: 0.0.1
- erlang: R16B03-1

#### RabbitMQ Log

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 28-Sep-2016::15:51:59 ===
** Generic server rabbit_delayed_message terminating
** Last message in was {delay_message,
                        {exchange,
                         {resource,<<"/">>,exchange,
                          <<"papyrus.hopeline.staging.requeue">>},
                         'x-delayed-message',true,false,false,
                         [{<<"x-delayed-type">>,longstr,<<"direct">>}],
                         undefined,undefined,
                         {[],[]}},
                        {delivery,false,false,<0.4340.2>,
                         {basic_message,
                          {resource,<<"/">>,exchange,
                           <<"papyrus.hopeline.staging.requeue">>},
                          [<<"papyrus.hopeline.staging.requeue">>],
                          {content,60,
                           {'P_basic',undefined,undefined,
                            [{<<"x-delay">>,signedint,600000}],
                            undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
                            undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
                            undefined},
                           <<32,0,0,0,0,13,7,120,45,100,101,108,97,121,73,0,9,
                             39,192>>,
                           rabbit_framing_amqp_0_9_1,
                           [<<"{\"_id\":\"579f380d9f3a78d60cb2063d\",\"__v\":2,\"created\":\"2016-08-01T11:52:45.346Z\",\"client\":{\"_id\":\"579f380d9f3a78d60cb2063b\"},\"assignedTo\":[{\"_id\":\"57ebd50f9e4a04b45444a639\",\"user\":{\"_id\":\"571e37f0cbd7a8ae2b73e925\",\"name\":\"Jason Royle\"},\"created\":\"2016-09-28T14:34:55.441Z\"},{\"_id\":\"57ebd52b9e4a04b45444a63b\",\"user\":{\"_id\":\"571e37f0cbd7a8ae2b73e925\",\"name\":\"Jason Royle\"},\"created\":\"2016-09-28T14:35:23.292Z\"}],\"assigned\":false}">>]},
                          <<85,201,10,44,175,144,74,190,136,41,55,79,176,130,
                            253,85>>,
                          false},
                         undefined,noflow},
                        600000}
** When Server state == {state,not_set}
** Reason for termination ==
** {'function not exported',
       [{erlang,system_time,[milli_seconds],[]},
        {rabbit_delayed_message,internal_delay_message,4,
            [{file,"src/rabbit_delayed_message.erl"},{line,179}]},
        {rabbit_delayed_message,handle_call,3,
            [{file,"src/rabbit_delayed_message.erl"},{line,122}]},
        {gen_server,handle_msg,5,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,585}]},
        {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}

=ERROR REPORT==== 28-Sep-2016::15:51:59 ===
** Generic server <0.4340.2> terminating
** Last message in was {'$gen_cast',
                           {method,
                               {'basic.publish',0,
                                   <<"papyrus.hopeline.staging.requeue">>,
                                   <<"papyrus.hopeline.staging.requeue">>,
                                   false,false},
                               {content,60,none,
                                   <<32,0,0,0,0,13,7,120,45,100,101,108,97,121,
                                     73,0,9,39,192>>,
                                   rabbit_framing_amqp_0_9_1,
                                   [<<"{\"_id\":\"579f380d9f3a78d60cb2063d\",\"__v\":2,\"created\":\"2016-08-01T11:52:45.346Z\",\"client\":{\"_id\":\"579f380d9f3a78d60cb2063b\"},\"assignedTo\":[{\"_id\":\"57ebd50f9e4a04b45444a639\",\"user\":{\"_id\":\"571e37f0cbd7a8ae2b73e925\",\"name\":\"Jason Royle\"},\"created\":\"2016-09-28T14:34:55.441Z\"},{\"_id\":\"57ebd52b9e4a04b45444a63b\",\"user\":{\"_id\":\"571e37f0cbd7a8ae2b73e925\",\"name\":\"Jason Royle\"},\"created\":\"2016-09-28T14:35:23.292Z\"}],\"assigned\":false}">>]},
                               flow}}
** When Server state == {ch,running,rabbit_framing_amqp_0_9_1,2,<0.4153.2>,
                            <0.4338.2>,<0.4153.2>,
                            <<"172.30.0.13:41896 -> 172.30.0.11:5672">>,
                            {lstate,<0.4339.2>,false},
                            none,1,
                            {[],[]},
                            {user,<<"developers">>,
                                [administrator],
                                [{rabbit_auth_backend_internal,none}]},
                            <<"/">>,<<>>,
                            {dict,0,16,16,8,80,48,
                                {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                 []},
                                {{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                  [],[]}}},
                            {state,
                                {dict,0,16,16,8,80,48,
                                    {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                     [],[],[]},
                                    {{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                      [],[],[]}}},
                                erlang},
                            {dict,0,16,16,8,80,48,
                                {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                 []},
                                {{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                  [],[]}}},
                            {dict,0,16,16,8,80,48,
                                {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                 []},
                                {{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                  [],[]}}},
                            {set,0,16,16,8,80,48,
                                {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                 []},
                                {{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                  [],[]}}},
                            <0.4154.2>,
                            {state,fine,5000,#Ref<0.0.0.136584>},
                            false,1,
                            {{0,nil},{0,nil}},
                            [],
                            {{0,nil},{0,nil}},
                            [{<<"publisher_confirms">>,bool,true},
                             {<<"exchange_exchange_bindings">>,bool,true},
                             {<<"basic.nack">>,bool,true},
                             {<<"consumer_cancel_notify">>,bool,true},
                             {<<"connection.blocked">>,bool,true},
                             {<<"authentication_failure_close">>,bool,true}],
                            none,0,none,flow,[]}
** Reason for termination ==
** {{{undef,
         [{erlang,system_time,[milli_seconds],[]},
          {rabbit_delayed_message,internal_delay_message,4,
              [{file,"src/rabbit_delayed_message.erl"},{line,179}]},
          {rabbit_delayed_message,handle_call,3,
              [{file,"src/rabbit_delayed_message.erl"},{line,122}]},
          {gen_server,handle_msg,5,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,585}]},
          {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]},
     {gen_server,call,
         [rabbit_delayed_message,
          {delay_message,
              {exchange,
                  {resource,<<"/">>,exchange,
                      <<"papyrus.hopeline.staging.requeue">>},
                  'x-delayed-message',true,false,false,
                  [{<<"x-delayed-type">>,longstr,<<"direct">>}],
                  undefined,undefined,
                  {[],[]}},
              {delivery,false,false,<0.4340.2>,
                  {basic_message,
                      {resource,<<"/">>,exchange,
                          <<"papyrus.hopeline.staging.requeue">>},
                      [<<"papyrus.hopeline.staging.requeue">>],
                      {content,60,
                          {'P_basic',undefined,undefined,
                              [{<<"x-delay">>,signedint,600000}],
                              undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
                              undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
                              undefined,undefined,undefined},
                          <<32,0,0,0,0,13,7,120,45,100,101,108,97,121,73,0,9,
                            39,192>>,
                          rabbit_framing_amqp_0_9_1,
                          [<<"{\"_id\":\"579f380d9f3a78d60cb2063d\",\"__v\":2,\"created\":\"2016-08-01T11:52:45.346Z\",\"client\":{\"_id\":\"579f380d9f3a78d60cb2063b\"},\"assignedTo\":[{\"_id\":\"57ebd50f9e4a04b45444a639\",\"user\":{\"_id\":\"571e37f0cbd7a8ae2b73e925\",\"name\":\"Jason Royle\"},\"created\":\"2016-09-28T14:34:55.441Z\"},{\"_id\":\"57ebd52b9e4a04b45444a63b\",\"user\":{\"_id\":\"571e37f0cbd7a8ae2b73e925\",\"name\":\"Jason Royle\"},\"created\":\"2016-09-28T14:35:23.292Z\"}],\"assigned\":false}">>]},
                      <<85,201,10,44,175,144,74,190,136,41,55,79,176,130,253,85>>,
                      false},
                  undefined,noflow},
              600000},
          infinity]}},
    [{gen_server,call,3,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,188}]},
     {rabbit_exchange_type_delayed_message,route,2,
         [{file,"src/rabbit_exchange_type_delayed_message.erl"},{line,53}]},
     {rabbit_exchange,route1,3,[{file,"src/rabbit_exchange.erl"},{line,381}]},
     {rabbit_exchange,route,2,[{file,"src/rabbit_exchange.erl"},{line,371}]},
     {rabbit_channel,handle_method,3,
         [{file,"src/rabbit_channel.erl"},{line,943}]},
     {rabbit_channel,handle_cast,2,
         [{file,"src/rabbit_channel.erl"},{line,457}]},
     {gen_server2,handle_msg,2,[{file,"src/gen_server2.erl"},{line,1032}]},
     {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}

=ERROR REPORT==== 28-Sep-2016::15:51:59 ===
Error on AMQP connection <0.4153.2> (172.30.0.13:41896 -> 172.30.0.11:5672, vhost: '/', user: 'developers', state: running), channel 2:
{{{undef,
      [{erlang,system_time,[milli_seconds],[]},
       {rabbit_delayed_message,internal_delay_message,4,
           [{file,"src/rabbit_delayed_message.erl"},{line,179}]},
       {rabbit_delayed_message,handle_call,3,
           [{file,"src/rabbit_delayed_message.erl"},{line,122}]},
       {gen_server,handle_msg,5,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,585}]},
       {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]},
  {gen_server,call,
      [rabbit_delayed_message,
       {delay_message,
           {exchange,
               {resource,<<"/">>,exchange,
                   <<"papyrus.hopeline.staging.requeue">>},
               'x-delayed-message',true,false,false,
               [{<<"x-delayed-type">>,longstr,<<"direct">>}],
               undefined,undefined,
               {[],[]}},
           {delivery,false,false,<0.4340.2>,
               {basic_message,
                   {resource,<<"/">>,exchange,
                       <<"papyrus.hopeline.staging.requeue">>},
                   [<<"papyrus.hopeline.staging.requeue">>],
                   {content,60,
                       {'P_basic',undefined,undefined,
                           [{<<"x-delay">>,signedint,600000}],
                           undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
                           undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
                           undefined},
                       <<32,0,0,0,0,13,7,120,45,100,101,108,97,121,73,0,9,39,
                         192>>,
                       rabbit_framing_amqp_0_9_1,
                       [<<"{\"_id\":\"579f380d9f3a78d60cb2063d\",\"__v\":2,\"created\":\"2016-08-01T11:52:45.346Z\",\"client\":{\"_id\":\"579f380d9f3a78d60cb2063b\"},\"assignedTo\":[{\"_id\":\"57ebd50f9e4a04b45444a639\",\"user\":{\"_id\":\"571e37f0cbd7a8ae2b73e925\",\"name\":\"Jason Royle\"},\"created\":\"2016-09-28T14:34:55.441Z\"},{\"_id\":\"57ebd52b9e4a04b45444a63b\",\"user\":{\"_id\":\"571e37f0cbd7a8ae2b73e925\",\"name\":\"Jason Royle\"},\"created\":\"2016-09-28T14:35:23.292Z\"}],\"assigned\":false}">>]},
                   <<85,201,10,44,175,144,74,190,136,41,55,79,176,130,253,85>>,
                   false},
               undefined,noflow},
           600000},
       infinity]}},
 [{gen_server,call,3,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,188}]},
  {rabbit_exchange_type_delayed_message,route,2,
      [{file,"src/rabbit_exchange_type_delayed_message.erl"},{line,53}]},
  {rabbit_exchange,route1,3,[{file,"src/rabbit_exchange.erl"},{line,381}]},
  {rabbit_exchange,route,2,[{file,"src/rabbit_exchange.erl"},{line,371}]},
  {rabbit_channel,handle_method,3,
      [{file,"src/rabbit_channel.erl"},{line,943}]},
  {rabbit_channel,handle_cast,2,[{file,"src/rabbit_channel.erl"},{line,457}]},
  {gen_server2,handle_msg,2,[{file,"src/gen_server2.erl"},{line,1032}]},
  {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}

=WARNING REPORT==== 28-Sep-2016::15:51:59 ===
Non-AMQP exit reason '{{{undef,
                         [{erlang,system_time,[milli_seconds],[]},
                          {rabbit_delayed_message,internal_delay_message,4,
                           [{file,"src/rabbit_delayed_message.erl"},
                            {line,179}]},
                          {rabbit_delayed_message,handle_call,3,
                           [{file,"src/rabbit_delayed_message.erl"},
                            {line,122}]},
                          {gen_server,handle_msg,5,
                           [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,585}]},
                          {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                           [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]},
                        {gen_server,call,
                         [rabbit_delayed_message,
                          {delay_message,
                           {exchange,
                            {resource,<<"/">>,exchange,
                             <<"papyrus.hopeline.staging.requeue">>},
                            'x-delayed-message',true,false,false,
                            [{<<"x-delayed-type">>,longstr,<<"direct">>}],
                            undefined,undefined,
                            {[],[]}},
                           {delivery,false,false,<0.4340.2>,
                            {basic_message,
                             {resource,<<"/">>,exchange,
                              <<"papyrus.hopeline.staging.requeue">>},
                             [<<"papyrus.hopeline.staging.requeue">>],
                             {content,60,
                              {'P_basic',undefined,undefined,
                               [{<<"x-delay">>,signedint,600000}],
                               undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
                               undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
                               undefined,undefined,undefined},
                              <<32,0,0,0,0,13,7,120,45,100,101,108,97,121,73,0,
                                9,39,192>>,
                              rabbit_framing_amqp_0_9_1,
                              [<<"{\"_id\":\"579f380d9f3a78d60cb2063d\",\"__v\":2,\"created\":\"2016-08-01T11:52:45.346Z\",\"client\":{\"_id\":\"579f380d9f3a78d60cb2063b\"},\"assignedTo\":[{\"_id\":\"57ebd50f9e4a04b45444a639\",\"user\":{\"_id\":\"571e37f0cbd7a8ae2b73e925\",\"name\":\"Jason Royle\"},\"created\":\"2016-09-28T14:34:55.441Z\"},{\"_id\":\"57ebd52b9e4a04b45444a63b\",\"user\":{\"_id\":\"571e37f0cbd7a8ae2b73e925\",\"name\":\"Jason Royle\"},\"created\":\"2016-09-28T14:35:23.292Z\"}],\"assigned\":false}">>]},
                             <<85,201,10,44,175,144,74,190,136,41,55,79,176,
                               130,253,85>>,
                             false},
                            undefined,noflow},
                           600000},
                          infinity]}},
                       [{gen_server,call,3,
                         [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,188}]},
                        {rabbit_exchange_type_delayed_message,route,2,
                         [{file,
                           "src/rabbit_exchange_type_delayed_message.erl"},
                          {line,53}]},
                        {rabbit_exchange,route1,3,
                         [{file,"src/rabbit_exchange.erl"},{line,381}]},
                        {rabbit_exchange,route,2,
                         [{file,"src/rabbit_exchange.erl"},{line,371}]},
                        {rabbit_channel,handle_method,3,
                         [{file,"src/rabbit_channel.erl"},{line,943}]},
                        {rabbit_channel,handle_cast,2,
                         [{file,"src/rabbit_channel.erl"},{line,457}]},
                        {gen_server2,handle_msg,2,
                         [{file,"src/gen_server2.erl"},{line,1032}]},
                        {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                         [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this was to upgrade the version of erlang as the system_time function of the erlang module only exists as of version 18. To install the latest version on centos I used [this rpm package](http://packages.erlang-solutions.com/site/esl/esl-erlang/FLAVOUR_1_general/esl-erlang_19.1~centos~7_amd64.rpm) to upgrade to version 19.1.